# PhoneGap default app cannot retrieve internet resources

Tags: cordova, default

this is my first question so please if I'm doing something wrong let me know.

So...

I created an app with PhoneGap windows phonegap application. I created my app. I changed just few lines of code like in the box below. I uploaded it to github. I built it on the online build service. Downloaded the apk and installed application.

There seems not to be any internet connection for the app.

```
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To:

```
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

It just won't load. Please help?

PS, in config.xml i have:

```
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
```

Comment: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Answer (score 0):

This can be marked as solved.

I hust used the cordova command line tool and it works. It does not with the adobe phonegap online builder. I dont know why using the command line helped, but I solved my problem